# POST request Parameters from Class based views - Pagination

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm using Django's Pagination Module with class-based views.

My Queryset will contain 1000+ objects, which I need to display one by one and based on the content displayed.

I don't need to show previous pages, I just need to Accept/Reject and on both the clicks, it should paginate to the next page.

I need to update few fields in the database based on Accept/Reject clicked by the user. How can I get the POST request parameters from the template in my class-based view? so that I can perform different steps on the click of Accept/Reject

Here's my code:

```
#views.py

from django.views.generic import ListView
class DemoView2(ListView):

    model = MandateTable
    template_name = 'demo2.html'
    context_object_name = 'pg'
    paginate_by = 1
    queryset = MandateTable.objects.all()[:5] #For Testing purspose, working on only 5 objects
```

Template

```
<!--demo2.html-->

{% for mandates in pg %}
        <p>{{ mandates.FIELD_1 }}</p>
        <p>{{ mandates.FIELD_2 }}</p>
        <p>{{ mandates.FELD_3 }}</p>
        <p>{{ mandates.FIELD_4 }}</p>
        <p>{{ mandates.FIELD_5 }}</p>
    {% endfor %}

{% if is_paginated %}
      <ul class="pagination">
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
          <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">&laquo;</a></li>
        {% else %}
          <li class="disabled"><span>&laquo;</span></li>
        {% endif %}

<button value="Accept" name="btn-accept" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">
            {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                <a style="text-decoration: none" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">Accept</a>
            {% else %}
                <a style="text-decoration: none" href="{% url 'demo' %}">Accept</a>
            {% endif %}
        </button>

        <button value="Reject" name="btn-reject" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">
            {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                <a style="text-decoration: none" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">Reject</a>
            {% else %}
                <a style="text-decoration: none" href="{% url 'demo' %}">Reject</a>
            {% endif %}
        </button>
      </ul>
{% endif %}
```

This is how my template is going to look
[image]

Im new to class-based views with Pagination.

Appreciate all the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution worked for me.

main.js

```
    $("#btn_reject").click(function () {
        //Fetch few parameters and send it along with clicked button in AJAX request
        var mNum = $("#mNum")[0].getAttribute('data-mn');
        var data = {"btn_name": "APPROVE", "m_number": mNum};
        man_verification(data);
    });

    $("#btn_reject").click(function () {
        //Fetch few parameters and send it along with clicked button in AJAX request
        var mNum = $("#mNum")[0].getAttribute('data-mn');
        var data = {"btn_name": "REJECT", "m_number": mNum};
        man_verification(data);
    });

     function man_verification(data) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/review/",
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
                //Code For Handlind Response Data
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log("Error", data);
            },
            beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
                if (!(/^http:.*/.test(settings.url) || /^https:.*/.test(settings.url))) {
                    // Only send the token to relative URLs i.e. locally.
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

views.py

```
class RevPageView(ListView):
    template_name = 'rev.html'
    queryset = db_query

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super(RevPageView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        try:
            #Get data from db
        paginator = Paginator(db_query, 1)
        page = self.request.GET.get('page')
        try:
            query = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            query = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            query = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
        context['data'] = query

        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data_status = None
        if request.is_ajax():
            get_pk = request.POST.get('mandate_number')
            m_status = request.POST.get('btn_name')

            #Make necessary changes to the db tables based on the received parameters

        data = {"data_status": data_status}
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

If there's a better and efficient approach than this would like to know about it :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this then:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.urls import reverse
class DemoView2(ListView):

    model = MandateTable
    template_name = 'demo2.html'
    context_object_name = 'pg'
    paginate_by = 1
    queryset = MandateTable.objects.all()[:5] #For Testing purspose, working on only 5 objects

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'accept' in request.POST:
            # do acceptable stuff
            pass
        elif 'reject' in request.POST:
            # do rejectable stuff
            pass
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        page_obj = context['page_obj']
        if page_obj.has_next():
            context['next'] = "?page=" + str(page_obj.next_page_number())
        else:
            context['next'] = reverse('demo')
        return context
```

---

```
<!--demo2.html-->

<form method='post'>
{% csrf_token %}

{% for mandates in pg %}
        <p>{{ mandates.FIELD_1 }}</p>
        <p>{{ mandates.FIELD_2 }}</p>
        <p>{{ mandates.FELD_3 }}</p>
        <p>{{ mandates.FIELD_4 }}</p>
        <p>{{ mandates.FIELD_5 }}</p>
    {% endfor %}

{% if is_paginated %}
      <ul class="pagination">
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
          <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">&laquo;</a></li>
        {% else %}
          <li class="disabled"><span>&laquo;</span></li>
        {% endif %}
        <button name='accept' class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" type="submit" formaction={{ next }}>Accept</button>

        <button name='reject' class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" type="submit" formaction={{ next }}>Reject</button>
      </ul>
{% endif %}
</form>
```

You would still need to somehow include the objects shown on that page into request.POST so you can do work on them (maybe by using hidden inputs). Never worked with pagination before.

Comment: It gives an AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'post' when clicked on the button

Comment: My bad, ListViews do not have a post method: just the get the response from the get method instead then. I just used the post method as you mentioned you wanted the data there.